# Normal text formatting does not work in custom href

Tags: hyperlink, href

I created my own `\href` definition because it had to meet some specific style requirements in my document. Now I found that the optional display text cannot be formatted like a usual text anymore. For example, spaces are being removed. To make it work initially, I took a solution from somewhere else (don't know where, sorry). This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=, linkcolor=, urlcolor=blue}
    \renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily\itshape} % still needs \nolinkurl
    \newcommand{\changeurlcolor}[1]{\hypersetup{urlcolor=#1}}
    \makeatletter
    \def\myhref{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
    \def\@with[#1]#2{\href{#2}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    \def\@without#1{\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    \makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent
% works as expected
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{Tex Stack Exchange}
\newline
% does not work as expected
\myhref[Tex Stack Exchange]{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well \nolinkurl uses \UrlFont, so I'm not sure what you mean that it doesn't work. Be aware that your command will not be able to handle urls with special chars like percent or hash.

Comment: And since `\nolinkurl` typesets a URL it ignores spaces (if that's what you're worried about).

Comment: And I'd suggest to define your `\myhref` in the following way instead: `\NewDocumentCommand \myhref { O{#2} m } {\href{#2}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}`.

Comment: I want the optional argument to be formatted like normal text, e.g. with spaces. Never really understood what `\nolinkurl` really does, but from your comments I assume it's just enough to remove it from `\def\@with[#1]#2{\href{#2}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}` and make it `\def\@with[#1]#2{\href{#2}{\itshape#1}}`?